# specific the location of the managed identity in an DeployIfNotExist azure policy

Tags: azure, azure-managed-identity, azure-policy

I'm writing a number of azure Policies and I'd like to specify the location of the managed identity in the JSON file rather than having to specify it as I assign the policy. 
In my Azure portal, when I go to assign the policy the managed identity location defaults to East US, and I have restricts that all resources must be located in the UK. As you can imagine having to deploy lots of policies and having to change the location of where the managed identity lives, is a real pain.

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

In the policy definition you can use the [field](http://Microsoft.Security/complianceResults/resourceStatus) location to help specify. If there are multiple locations, you can do a array of parameters.